# Remove vertical white line in the middle of IDE code editor

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I'm using 2 monitors. On the 2nd one, I have the Delphi IDE, using the Classic undocked settings.

There is a white vertical line in the middle of the IDE cutting through the source code. I can't seems to find the option in the settings to remove it.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That line is the Code Editor's "Right margin".  You can turn that on/off in the [Display](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Display) section of the [Code Editor settings](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Editor_Options), or you can set how many characters from the left edge of the editor you want the line to appear (the default is 80 chars).

See [Customizing the Code Editor](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Customizing_the_Code_Editor) for more details.